# Why do here-documents attempt shell substitution even on a commented line?

Tags: bash, cat, variable-substitution

I wanted to see how some ASCII art looked in terminal so:

```
$ cat <<EOF                                                                                                                                                                                  
> #          ____         _
> #  _   _  / __/  ___ _ | |_
> # | | | |/ /    /  _` || __|
> # | |_| |\ \__  (_| || |_
> # |  _,_| \___\ \___,_| \__|
> # |_/
> #
> EOF
bash: bad substitution: no closing "`" in ` || __|
# | |_| |\ \__  (_| || |_
# |  _,_| \___\ \___,_| \__|
# |_/
#
```

The `#` octothorpes were there perchance, but now I'm confused.

```
$ cat <<EOF
> # echo hi
> EOF
# echo hi
```

As expected.

However:

```
$ cat <<EOF
> # `echo hello`
> EOF
# hello
```

So `bash` gets at expanding ``` `` ``` and `$( )` before `cat` does, but it doesn't care about `#` comments? What's the explanation behind this behaviour?

Comment: Change `cat <<EOF` to `cat <<\EOF`.

Comment: If the commented line was output, then clearly it's not a comment.

Comment: @muru I don't mean a comment in that `cat` will ignore it, I meant a comment to be ignored by `bash`.

Comment: Since `cat` doesn't have any concept of comments at all, we're both talking of bash. A comment shouldn't affect the outcome *at all*. If it does, it's not a comment.

Comment: Is that micro cat? Is there a macro cat? You oughtta go big before you go small

Comment: @mikeserv i am the macro cat :) [microcat](http://github.com/catb0t/microcat)

Comment: Oh geez. Youre writing a programmibg language in python? Thats... Horrifying.

Comment: @mikeserv [i've done it before (well, this one is far from done)](http://github.com/catb0t/mouse16) and... hey, what's wrong with Python? I'm only using it because I know and like it. If I knew and liked Perl 6 as much as I do Python, I'd use that instead.

Comment: Whats wrong w/ python? There are about a million correct answers to that quwstion.

Comment: @mikeserv okay, I'm not using C or C++ or C# or Java because they don't provide easy ways to get at the kind of functionality I'm looking to implement.

Comment: Easy != good. Rarely do the two converge, actually.

Comment: @mikeserv let me rephrase that: they provide almost no practical, sensical way to implement what I want to.

Comment: Python is awful. So i cant believe you find it practical or sensical.

Comment: @cat im sorry for earlier disregard to your perfectly valid "whats wrong with" question... the answer is about a million pieces... try a `find` on a default `pythonv[0-9.]*` install and result a fiasco unreliable to healthy auditing. for example, here i have some 1500 answers... and that is a responsibility vast to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is more general than bash.  In POSIX shell, your `EOF` is referred to as a *word*, in the discussion of [here-documents](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04):

> If no characters in *word* are quoted, all lines of the here-document shall be expanded for parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. In this case, the *`<backslash>`* in the input behaves as the *`<backslash>`* inside double-quotes (see Double-Quotes). However, the double-quote character ( `'"'` ) shall not be treated specially within a here-document, except when the double-quote appears within `"$()"`, ``` "``" ```, or `"${}"`.

Quoting is done using single-, double-quotes or the backslash character.  POSIX mentions the here-documents in the discussion of [quoting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02):

> The various quoting mechanisms are the escape character, single-quotes, and double-quotes. The here-document represents another form of quoting; see [Here-Document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04).

The key to understanding the lack of treatment of `#` characters is the definition for here-documents:

> allow *redirection* of lines contained in a shell input file

That is, no meaning (other than possible parameter expansion, etc) is given to the data by the shell, because the data is *redirected* to another program: `cat`, which is not a shell interpreter.  If you redirected to a *shell program*, the result would be whatever the shell could do with the data.

Comment: Perhaps better reason why `#` does not introduce comment in here-document is that it does not introduce comment in quoted string either and here-documents behave as quoted strings.

Comment: For that, you have to do more reading between the lines, because POSIX does not mention comments and quoting in the same sentence (I think).  Redirecting was the closest I found.

Comment: A `#` does not introduce a comment in a here document for the same reason it does not introduce a comment in `"# $(echo foo)"`: a string is data, not code.

Answer (score 9):

Within a here document there are no comment lines.

`man bash`:

> No parameter  and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any characters
>   in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the  here-document  are  not  expanded. If word  is unquoted,  all  lines  of  the  here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \ is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.

So you need:

```
cat <<"EOF"
```